# Can I use the Google App Script trigger more often than every minute?

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, triggers, cron

Google app script gives you the possibility to easily trigger the script even every minute. However, I would like to trigger an event every 15 seconds ? can I do it easily ?

Or maybe other companies offer similar tools which are easy to configure?

[image]

Comment: You could launch a sidebar and set up a setInterval and let it trigger call your server side function every 15 seconds as long as clients side dialog stay active.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations are off-topic here. Try [softwarerecs.se]. Regarding a faster Google Apps Script trigger frequency, it's not possible, but there are many options. If you need more details about Cooper suggestion or the Dmitry answer, please [edit] the question to provide further details about your use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. However, you can have a parent function run a child function 4 times with a 15 second delay, for example:

```js
// This is the function that gets triggered by your trigger every minute
function parentFunction() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    childFunction();
    Utilities.sleep(15000); // sleep for 15 seconds
  }
}

function childFunction() {
  // this function does whatever you need
  // 4 times per every trigger execution
  // which is 4 times per minutes or every 15 seconds
}
```